# Get height of UITableView without scroll bars

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I need to get the full height of a `UITableView` (i.e. the height at which there would be nothing more to scroll). Is there any way to do this?

I've tried `[tableView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero]`, but that only returns a 0x0 `CGSize`.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Try the `contentSize` method, which is inherited from UITableView’s superclass, UIScrollView. However, you may find that `contentSize` returns an incorrect or out of date value, so you should probably call `layoutIfNeeded` first to recalculate the table’s layout.

```
- (CGFloat)tableViewHeight
{
   [tableView layoutIfNeeded];
   return [tableView contentSize].height;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Obligatory **Swift 3.0** & **2.2** answer.

```
var tableViewHeight: CGFloat {
    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

    return tableView.contentSize.height
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try passing in a different CGSize parameter instead of CGSizeZero. The sizeThatFits: method uses that parameter to calculate its result. Try passing in self.view.size from whatever class is making that call.

Answer (score -2):

If a table view rows count changed and you indeed need to know the content size of table view incorporating the last changes, I didn't find that layoutIfNeeded method actually helps.

After a little bit hacking, I get to know how to force table view recalculate its content size. In my case, it is enough to reset table view frame to get it working:

```
- (CGSize)com_lohika_contentSize
{
    CGRect theFrame = self.frame;
    self.frame = CGRectZero;
    self.frame = theFrame;
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
    return [self contentSize];
}
```