# Tableview not using all available space

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have an IOS application containing, amongst other view controllers, a view controller with a `UIScrollView` and `UITableView`. This is launched with
    self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier.

I hope this maybe something simple, but I cannot get the table view to use all its available space, i.e. the `UITableView` has enough height for say 4 rows, but it starts to make use of scroll bar when there is only 3 rows in the table.

Regarding the scrollview, I have some horizontal content which is only 25 in height, but if I make the `UIScrollView` anything less than 110 in height or so, then the horizontal content will only appear partially on screen or not at all.

Xcode 4.4.1 on OSX Lion, IOS 5.1

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide log of tableView height in viewDidAppear(or after loading table) & code in heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Do you have a `UITableView` AND a `UIScrollView`? If so, are they nested? `UITableView` has its own scroll view that it manages automatically.

Comment: @AndreasLey The UITableView and the UIScrollView are not nested. They are at the same level in the overall View.

Comment: @Rahul I haven't done a heightForRowAtIndexPath (Is this what I am missing?). I did [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528073/get-height-of-uitableview-without-scroll-bars) to get table height. It starts with 0 and increment 45 each row is added in runtime, but after 3 rows, scrollbar appears (when 4th row is added, 1st row is rolled off). 45 is the height of the tablecell in my storyboard.

Comment: Do you have autoresizing enabled for the `UITableView`?

Comment: @AndreasLey I turned off "Autoresize subviews" on the View in Attributes Inspector. No effect. I noticed one thing though, when there is no data in the table view, it draws 5 blank rows on screen. Each data row is added in turn, the 4th and 5th blank rows disappears when the 3rd data row is added. When the 4th data row is added, scrolling begins.

Comment: We really need more information to be able to help you. Autoresizing might be required (and the `UITableView` set to autoresize horizontally and vertically), but it's hard to tell since we barely know anything about your view's layout.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem myself (Trying to find a host to put some screenshots. Will update).

I set the Bottom Bar from Inferred to Tab Bar in the Attribute Inspector and it now works. Both the previously unusable spaces in the ScrollBar and the TableView can now be used. These space were both of the size of the Tab bar. Took a while to work this out, as even before this change, the tab bar was showing on the simulator, so I didn't think it was Tab Bar related.

Comment: try using facebook to host your images