# i want dynamic get uitableview total height,not uitableviewcell,

Tags: ios, uitableview, height

I want dynamic get uitableview total height,not `UITableViewCell`, not frame, and i find `self.tableView.contentSize.height=0` for the first time, so i am very trouble in this problem,i need help please.

thanks...

Comment: I guess you want to add something in the end of `table`? In this case you can use `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section` function to add a view in the footer of the `tableview` it will simply add a footer that will come in the end of the tableview..

Comment: you help me so much...thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use contentSize property of UITableView, but you should layout tableView first.
Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2528123/1158590

Answer (score 3):

The `self.tableView.contentSize.height` is the proper way to do it, but you have to load the table view before calling this, so put a `[tableView reloadData];` before calling `self.tableView.contentSize.height`.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.mainTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    
    [self.mainTableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.mainTableView setDataSource:self];
    [self.mainTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.mainTableView];
    
    [self addPullToRefreshFooter];
}   -(void)addPullToRefreshFooter
{
    [self.mainTableView reloadData];
    
    NSLog(@"mainHeight : %f  %f",self.mainTableView.contentSize.height,self.mainTableView.frame.size.height);                                                }

Comment: Do you have any data in tableView ?

Comment: YES,i use dataArr,and dataArr has 11 count